# Training spaCy's NER model from scratch on CoNLL 2003 data got very weird results

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, training-data, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to try training NER models using spaCy from scratch. I wanted to first try it out on [CoNLL 2003 data](https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/NeuroNER/tree/master/data/conll2003/en), which is widely used as a baseline for NER systems.

The following are the commands I ran:

```
spacy convert -c ner train.txt valid.txt test.txt spacyConverted
cd spacyConverted
python -m spacy train en trained train.txt.json valid.txt.json --no-tagger --no-parser
mkdir displacy
python -m spacy evaluate trained/model-final test.txt.json --displacy-path displacy
```

However, the evaluation results on test data are very weird and totally off, as seen in the following displacy output.

[image: results]

The precision, recall and f1 scores are very low both during the training and the evaluation.

[image: training]

I do believe that the commands are correct and in accordance with the documentation. What could be the possible problem here? Could it be that I must supply some word vectors as well? If so, how do I supply those that come by default in spaCy? Or could it be that one cannot use `--no-tagger --no-parser`?

The converted `.json` files look like the following:

```
[
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"-DOCSTART-",
                "tag":"-X-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"EU",
                "tag":"NNP",
                "ner":"U-ORG"
              },
              {
                "orth":"rejects",
                "tag":"VBZ",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "orth":"German",
                "tag":"JJ",
                "ner":"U-MISC"
              },
              {
                "orth":"call",
                "tag":"NN",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "orth":"to",
                "tag":"TO",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              ...
```

---

EDIT: It seemed that I actually needed to pass in the `--gold-preproc` flag for the training to properly work. But I'm not sure what it actually means in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem on your pre-processing. Review the pre-processing step, you have to collect a list of sentences where each line is a token a and new line separate sentences from each other.

Also, pay attention to these tokens:

> -DOCSTART-

They are just separators between documents. I had that problem as well, and my results were bad. If you want [have a look at how I pre-process it](https://github.com/davidsbatista/SLANG/blob/master/slang/corpus_processing.py), to use it for other purposes not for spaCy.